# swift-custom keyboard on ios 8

Tags: ios, iphone, keyboard, swift, ios-app-extension

I made a custom keyboard using swift.
While doing that, I made vertically. It crashes when I rotate the device to landscape.
Keyboard is also vertical, with the horizontal space of the other so much.
I do not know if any of you have a solution or some advice here.

portrait
[image]

landscape
[image]

Comment: Both the link is same..

Comment: Please add how you fixed it as an answer so others can benefit.

Comment: OK, but now I still can not fix it.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: I discovered a method using override func viewWillLayoutSubviews ().